# Duplicate data when testing with nodejs/mocha/mongoose

Tags: node.js

I'm running asynchronous tests with nodeJS/mocha/mongoose and I keep getting duplicate documents in my collection when I run a test like the following.

```
const assert = require('assert');
const User = require('../src/user');

describe('Duplicates records test', () => {

    beforeEach((done) => {
        let user = new User({ name: 'Bob'});
        user.save()
            .then(() => done()); 
    });

    it('Return users named Bob', (done) => {
        User.find({ name: 'Bob' })
            .then((users) => {
                console.log(users);
                done();
            });

    });
});
```

The following is the model I'm using:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: String
});

const User = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

The following is the output from running the test:

```
[ { _id: 5c918ca6d4b6eb4416312226, name: 'Bob', __v: 0 },
{ _id: 5c918ca6c2589d4415a4317a, name: 'Bob', __v: 0 } ]

1 passing (2s)
```

And finally the output from mongodb:

```
> db.users.find().pretty()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c918ca6d4b6eb4416312226"), "name" : "Bob", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c918ca6c2589d4415a4317a"), "name" : "Bob", "__v" : 0 }
```

I have several tests like this in my suite and this only seems to happen when I save records inside of a beforeEach statement. Any insight as to why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably happening because you have no logic to drop the previous record saved when you fire off the next test.

To avoid duplicate records when you are testing with NodeJS/Mocha/mongoose you want to add some logic to drop the collections at least when running your server for testing.

You have not shared your `package.json` file, but I would recommend a script that looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test nodemon --exec 'mocha --recursive -R min'"
  },
```

So `NODE_ENV` is an environment variable and environment variables are used to customize the behavior or encode some constants to access inside an application and you can use `NODE_ENV` variable to specify if the server is running in development, production or whatever.

So this will help you in seeing if it needs to empty out the collection of users.

To do so, you can make a reference to the variable `process.env.NODE_ENV`.

Wherever you are making your connection to Mongo, you want to add an if statement like so:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "test") {
  mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/user", { useMongoClient: true });
}
```

So what you are saying here is, when running in development just start up the sever and connect to the database but when running in test, start up the server, connect to the database and drop the collections, but that is not the solution in and of itself.

What I would recommend is creating a separate database that would be called `user_test` and then create a separate helper file with the logic for connecting to that database.

So you are going to have two separate databases.

So in the if statement above you are saying if I am running in a development or production environment, if its not equal to test, then connect to this database. If I am running in test do not connect to this database.

Then you add that test helper file to the application that will be used to connect to mongoose. Why a separate test helper file? because it will make it easier to ensure the test suite only starts up once the connection to the test database has been achieved.

Keep in mind that Mocha and Mongoose don't really play well together or at least not in my opinion.

This is also helpful because you do not have to wrap the connection string with an `if` statement to check if you are in the test environment. If the test helper file is executed then yeah you are in the test environment so you don’t have to make it explicit. That logic would look something like this:

```
const mongoose = require(‘mongoose’);

before((done) => {
    mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/user_test”, { useMongoClient: true });
});
```

So now the `user_test` database can get dropped all day long and nothing bad is going to happen, you won’t be touching the development data and so later you can even customize that development database to have some data that you might want to have stick around.

You also place handlers for looking at the connection status and once the connection is open you can use a done callback like so:

```
const mongoose = require(‘mongoose’);

before((done) => {
    mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/user_test”, { useMongoClient: true });
    mongoose.connection.once(‘open’, () => done())
});
```

If there is ever an error you can launch a `console.warn()` like so:

```
const mongoose = require(‘mongoose’);

before((done) => {
    mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/muber_test”, { useMongoClient: true });
    mongoose.connection.once(‘open’, () => done()).on(‘error’, (err) => {
        console.warn(‘Warning’, error);
    });
});
```

I like this solution because if you locate all the logic inside of the test itself, sometimes Mocha will execute the test before the connection has been made to the database which means all the tests will fail as a result.

Almost forgot the most important part, dropping the collection:

```
const mongoose = require(‘mongoose’);
    
    before((done) => {
        mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/muber_test”, { useMongoClient: true });
        mongoose.connection.once(‘open’, () => done()).on(‘error’, (err) => {
            console.warn(‘Warning’, error);
        });
    });

beforeEach((done) => {
    const { users } = mongoose.connection.collections;
    users.drop().then(() => done()).catch(() => done());
});
```

The reason we have that `catch()` in there for `done()` is that it handles the very first time your database runs, you do not have yet a users collection in existence and that would throw an error and that's why we add that to handle the case.